# responsive image mapping with coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to understand how this plugin works :http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

The goal is to have responsive image maping but what I dont understand is how to come up with the coords. See below how there are a bunch of numbers, how do I calculate my own coords for my image, can some one explain what is going on with this demo and how it is to be used?

```
<map name="powerpuffgirls">
    <area shape="poly" coords="122,36,281,36,285,37,287,39,289,42,289,47,289,48,278,77,276,81,274,84,271,85,218,85,218,90,210,90,208,95,207,99,204,100,72,100,26,87,23,84,20,81,19,76,35,40,37,38,43,35,62,35,65,30,68,26,72,25,115,25,119,27,121,30,122,36,122,36" href="#ppg" title="The Powerpuff Girls" alt="The Powerpuff Girls" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="864,668,912,650,922,668,971,667,973,718,981,722,985,729,988,731,1010,731,1010,742,833,742,833,730,865,730,865,721,874,721,874,718,864,668,864,668" href="#cn" title="Cartoon Network" alt="Cartoon Network" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="1010,298,995,281,979,267,962,256,944,248,927,242,909,238,876,236,857,237,838,240,817,246,797,255,778,266,761,281,746,299,735,322,730,335,728,346,726,348,721,349,709,344,711,361,718,378,708,380,697,388,688,398,685,404,685,411,686,419,691,425,698,429,707,431,735,426,743,427,752,433,762,444,774,454,798,469,787,483,779,481,772,482,761,486,753,495,747,505,746,516,746,521,748,527,751,532,759,538,741,561,734,572,732,584,733,591,737,599,744,604,754,607,765,604,776,597,797,570,817,543,857,488,865,488,893,488,910,485,924,483,930,483,935,485,939,490,934,496,931,501,929,506,932,514,938,519,945,522,954,523,966,521,979,516,985,512,989,507,993,500,994,493,991,484,986,476,967,464,982,454,998,440,1013,425,1024,409,1024,329,1017,312,1010,298,1010,298" href="#buttercup" title="Buttercup" alt="Buttercup" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="571,101,563,83,562,66,549,80,541,96,537,112,536,128,537,141,531,141,508,141,508,141,511,133,517,126,533,114,500,111,476,111,452,114,438,118,424,124,410,131,400,140,392,152,390,167,391,174,394,183,400,191,409,198,391,215,379,234,371,252,368,271,367,277,368,298,371,316,381,338,396,358,414,375,399,378,387,385,379,393,377,405,378,412,382,418,388,424,395,429,411,434,425,435,431,446,439,456,459,474,480,488,502,500,514,507,523,515,528,523,530,534,529,541,526,547,515,562,532,556,548,547,562,536,574,523,583,508,590,490,594,470,596,448,596,430,591,410,587,398,599,390,613,382,628,371,643,356,657,337,666,313,669,299,670,284,669,276,668,264,670,263,697,263,704,261,711,257,716,251,719,243,718,236,715,231,706,221,694,215,683,213,677,213,670,215,664,220,656,232,645,215,652,206,657,199,660,191,662,181,660,169,655,158,648,150,638,142,617,130,596,120,582,112,571,101,571,101" href="#blossom" title="Blossom" alt="Blossom" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="254,286,232,271,207,260,179,254,150,252,119,254,103,257,88,263,71,270,61,275,58,274,57,273,45,269,36,268,17,271,7,276,1,283,0,283,0,285,0,290,0,352,2,354,1,355,1,390,3,401,5,410,9,420,22,441,39,460,58,476,47,480,38,487,32,494,30,504,33,515,41,524,53,531,69,534,77,533,85,530,90,525,93,518,91,512,88,508,85,505,85,502,86,499,89,497,97,496,120,500,138,503,154,503,167,503,185,531,215,576,235,609,241,617,248,622,255,626,265,628,273,626,280,621,285,614,287,605,283,592,276,580,261,558,269,553,273,547,276,541,277,536,274,524,267,513,257,504,250,501,244,501,240,502,237,503,225,488,242,478,259,468,276,451,282,447,292,446,318,450,327,448,334,445,339,439,341,431,337,419,329,409,318,401,307,398,301,398,301,393,301,391,303,391,321,393,336,391,352,387,370,380,387,370,373,368,364,364,358,360,353,354,350,347,347,330,345,313,343,302,340,293,336,286,331,280,318,272,305,267,293,266,282,267,272,270,262,276,254,286,254,286" href="#bubbles" title="Bubbles" alt="Bubbles" />
</map>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you look at the plugin's source code to see how they did it?  The demo seems to adjust the coords based on changes on the viewport.  Perhaps they are simply calculating the % in change in the viewport and applying (scaling) that same change to all the coords?

Comment: For more help on image maps: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp  OR http://www.lissaexplains.com/fun6.shtml OR http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/imagemaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin does the heavy lifting for you.

From what I can see, the coords are whatever you want... the plug in then calculates the new coords based on the size of the image. These obtuse coordinates are for a complete outline of the powerpfuff girls and the logos... try something simple like a circle or a rectangle.

Comment: But where do the original coordinates come from, how does it know to do a shape around each girl? or are all thous number the original cords and we just dont see the plugins conversions?

Comment: i think you as the designer/developer place the original coords, and then the plugin alters them as needed... what does the GIT say...https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a way to create the coordinates, you can use various apps on your computer or you can also do this online such as [image-maps.com](https://www.image-maps.com). Just do a search online for "online image map editors" and several will show up.

Simply upload your image or add a URL of your image and then create the shapes (rectangle, polygon, circle) with corresponding links etc. and it will output the code for you.